# Is $L^p(X,\ell^p)$, $1<p<\infty$, uniformly convex?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a measure space and let $1<p<\infty$.

> **Question.** Is the space $L^p(X,\ell^p)$,
> $$
> \lVert f\rVert_p=\Bigl(\int_X\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lvert f_i\rvert^p\, dx\Bigr)^{1/p},
> \qquad
> f=(f_i)_{i=1}^\infty,
> $$
> uniformly convex?

If the answer if "yes" I would appreciate a reference to the statement/proof.

I know that $L^p(X,\ell^p_M)$, where $\ell^p_M$ is finite dimensional $\ell^p$ space
$$
\lVert f\rVert_p=\Bigl(\int_X\sum_{i=1}^M \lvert f_i\rvert^p\, dx\Bigr)^{1/p},
\qquad
f=(f_1,\dotsc,f_M)
$$
is uniformly convex. This result was proved by Clarkson in [Uniformly convex spaces](https://doi.org/10.2307/1989630) where he introduced the notion; see also [Uniformly convex Banach spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/q/420011/121665). I haven't checked whether the argument applies to the case of values into $\ell^p$.

Comment: Isn't $L^p(X,\ell^p)$ isometric to $L^p(X\times \mathbb N)$, $X\times \mathbb N$ with the product measure?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I think you are correct and I feel like a moron. If you post your comment as n answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By Proposition  1.2.24 in T. Hytonen, J. Van Neerven, M. Veraar and L. Weis, Analyis in Banach spaces Vol I, Springer, the spaces $L^p(X; \ell^p)$ and $L^p(X\times \mathbb N)$, $X \times \mathbb N$ with the product measure,  are isometric (at least when $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite). Then the uniform convexity of $L^p(X; \ell^p)$ follows from that of $L^p$-spaces.